# R Calculation of sum from the value if the column is NA

Tags: r

I have a csv which has 10 thousand rows of data which consists of 5 columns which are Name, Age, Sex, Money and Sum.

- I need to perform the for loop through the Age column and check if it is empty.
- If it is empty meaning NA, then I need to perform the sum(calculation) under the Sum column from the value, Money

For example, from the data below,

1. for the Name which is Tan and the Age is NA which pass the criteria which is NA
2. I need to perform the calculation of the number from the Money column and then provide the value under the Sum column.

I will show the top 5 rows of data.

```
Name    Age    Sex    Money    Sum
Alex    50     M      50       NA
James   20     M      30       NA
Tan     NA     F      40       NA
Andy    35     M      70       NA
David   NA     M      60       NA
```

R code

```
for(externalitem in df$Age)
{
    if(is.na(externalitem)
    {
    
       #perform calculation of money column and provide the under the sum value under the sum column
    }
}
```

How to achieve it? I want to perform looping through the Age column and check if it is empty. if it is empty, then I want to grab the data from the Money column and then perform calculation and load the data to Sum column.

Comment: This is not clear. What is looping "over all columns" - the check if NA? What is the expected output for this sample input? In your example data, is the answer 40 + 60 = 100 because those are the `Money` values when `Age` is `NA`? If so, where does the `100` go? If not, what is the answer and where does it go?

Comment: What variable do you want to sum?

Comment: I want to sum the variable, Money column and perform some calculation. but the calculation is complicated. I am more concerned on how to select specifc column when looping

Comment: @GregorThomas Basically, I want to first loop through the Age column and then if it is empty, then I perform the grabbing of data from Money and perform calculation and then put the value in the Sum column

Comment: `sum(df$Money[is.na(df$Age)]` will sum the Money values when Age is `NA`. No loop needed. It doesn't make sense to put that in another columns, because it is a single value, and is related to many rows (whenever Age is `NA`), not a single row.